# issue using strings with c++ minGW Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, mingw

I am using the gcc compiler that comes with minGW on Windows 10. When I try to compile a simple hello world program named hello.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    std::string x = "hello world";

    int main() { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
```

when I compile it with the command g++ test.cpp -o test
it compiles fine, but when I try running the exe, I get the following error popup.

the procedure entry point _znkst7__cxx1112basic_stringlcst11char_traitslcESalcEEC1EPKcRKS3_ could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\mingw_dev_lib\test.exe

I've added minGW to my path as tutorials instructed, and can compile and run a version of the hello world program that doesn't use the string library (but still uses iostream) just fine. googling around it seems that some people with similar problems sorted it out by reinstalling minGW, but I reinstalled minGW and recompiled the hello world program and had same issue. Any ideas on what is going wrong?

Comment: `dynamic link library C:\mingw_dev_lib\test.exe` -- That's an odd name for a dynamic link library

Comment: Unable to reproduce.I'm using g++ 7.1.0 from the MinGW w64 project. I believe the latest version is 7.3

Comment: For painless GCC installation on Windows, see http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/

Comment: Possibly a relevant point: I discovered recently that Visual C++ in Windows 10 Really Doesn't Like™ that a source file is called "_.cpp". Weird. (And now I'm unable to reproduce THAT, so maybe it could be anti-virus messing things up?).

Comment: What's your compile command line?

Comment: My command Line is just the built in windows command prompt.

Comment: What are you TYPING at the command prompt to compile your code??

Comment: g++ test.cpp -o test

Comment: Well, that looks ok.